# Swift: multiple functions working at the same time

Tags: swift, uibutton, avaudioplayer, viewcontroller

In my app I have 2 UIButtons, each button plays 2 sounds (plays one sound, pauses, plays the other sound), and the UIButtons image changes every time it is pressed, my app also has a few tabs.the problem is that when I press a UIButton (which takes about 4 seconds for the sounds to be played and be done) I can not press another button, or even switch between tabs, the app freezes until the action of UIbutton gets done with, then I can press other buttons or switch tabs.
here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreData


class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var player2:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    player.play()
    sleep(1)
    player2.play()
}

@IBAction func play2(_ sender: Any) {
    player.play()
    sleep(1)
    player2.play()  
}


@IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var play2: UIButton!

var buttonActive = false

@IBAction func pPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if buttonActive {
        play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Switch-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
    }
    buttonActive = !buttonActive
}

@IBAction func p2Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if buttonActive {
        play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Switch-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
    }
    buttonActive = !buttonActive
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
    play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)

do

    {

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DTMF-1", ofType: "mp3")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

        let audioPath2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DTMF-2", ofType: "mp3")
        try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath2!) as URL)

 }
```

Is there any way to make my app be faster?

Comment: The most important thing is that **you must not call `sleep(_:)` in the main thread**. And your question is not clear enough. You have four actions for just two buttons. How have you connected each button to the actions? And the sentence _they only work one at a time_, an `AVAudioPlayer` can play one sound at a time, do you need to play the sound for button1 and the sound for button2 simultaneously? Or you can stop the sound for button1 when button2 is pressed?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: You really have updated your question, without answering to what I'm asking...

Comment: I've got them actions connected to the UIButton by Touch Up Inside events, they work pretty well. I know `AVAudioPlayer` can only play one, I want it to stop when I press another button, OR when I switch tabs, I don't want the app to freeze and wait for the `AVAudioPlayer` to finish and then start working, I want the AVAudioPlayer to keep working while I'm doing other stuff in the app.

Comment: The second question of mine has gotten clear. But not my first. Which button to which actions? (and it's order.) And you are using one of the freeze-my-app functions, it's named `sleep`.

Comment: 4 actions: 2 UIButton Image change, and 2 "Players" (which plays 2 tones each".   Each UIButton plays 2 tones and then it's Image changes. And to your last sentence: is there any other code for making a 0.5 second pause between playing 2 or more tones in on button? Even heard a phone tone on redial? That's how my app sounds when you play a UIButton

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough myself. You have two `UIButton`s, `play` and `play2`. You have four action methods `play`, `play2`, `pPressed` and `p2Pressed`. To which action methods and in what order, the `UIButton` `play` is connected? And to which action methods and in what order, the `UIButton` `play2` is connected? And for your _is there any other code for making a 0.5 second pause between playing 2 or more tones in on button?_, YES, numbers of ways, and all I know never uses `sleep`.

Comment: The UIButton “play” action methods are: play, pPressed | the UIButton “play2” action methods are: play2, p2Pressed. And instead of “sleep” what other code can you recommend?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll show you an alternative as an answer. And I need to correct one thing -- you may call `sleep` in background threads, but it's a sort of overkill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One famous way to implement *do something, **pause** and do other thing* is to use `Timer`.

The following code also includes:

- How to properly instantiate `AVAudioPlayer`
- How to invalidate working `Timer`
- How to `stop` `AVAudioPlayer` when it may be reused soon
- How to stop playing on transition

Please try:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer? //### You should not instantiate unused objects

    var player2: AVAudioPlayer?

    var secondSoundTimer: Timer?

    private func startPlaying() {
        stopPlaying()

        player?.play()
        //### Using `Timer` is one way to achieve pause-like thing.
        //### If you need to target older iOSs than 10.0, you need to modify this part.
        secondSoundTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) {timer in
            self.player2?.play()
            self.secondSoundTimer?.invalidate()
            self.secondSoundTimer = nil
        }
    }

    private func stopPlaying() {
        secondSoundTimer?.invalidate()
        secondSoundTimer = nil
        if let player = player, player.isPlaying {
            //### Stop playing (keeping internal `prepared` state) and rewind to the first place.
            player.pause()
            player.currentTime = 0
        }
        if let player2 = player2, player2.isPlaying {
            player2.pause()
            player2.currentTime = 0
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var play2: UIButton!

    var buttonActive = false

    @IBAction func pPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        startPlaying()
        if buttonActive {
            play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Switch-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
        }
        buttonActive = !buttonActive
    }

    //### Don't you need `button2Active`?

    @IBAction func p2Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
        startPlaying()
        if buttonActive {
            play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Switch-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
        }
        buttonActive = !buttonActive
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        play.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)
        play2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SwitchD-Icon-40"), for: .normal)

        do {
            //### You can get URL directly from Bundle
            //### It's better to apply forced-unwrapping as soon as possible, if you need it eventually.
            let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DTMF-1", withExtension: "mp3")!
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)
            //### `prepareToPlay()` improves response for the first play.
            player?.prepareToPlay()

            let audioURL2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DTMF-2", withExtension: "mp3")!
            player2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL2)
            player2?.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            //... or any other things you need...
        }

        //...
    }

    //### Stop playing on transition to other ViewConrollers.
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        stopPlaying()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shahin, sorry, I should have mentioned it in my answer. Connecting more than one action to a single button can easily cause unexpected behavior, so I removed the two action. To test my code, you need to remove two action connections -- `play` button to `play` action and `play2` button to `play2` action. Instead I put `startPlaying()` into two actions `pPressed` and `p2Pressed`.

Comment: I got it, but what if I need to add more than two `player`s? into my `private function`s? how does that work?

Comment: @Shahin, you may use `thirdSoundTimer`, `fourthSoundTimer`,... Or there may be some other ways. But you really need it? If you really need it, you'd better start a new thread for it. I believe there are many who can answer it.

Comment: yea I need it, You're right, thanks for the time and info